# Extract variable with same title from dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a huge data set. Here is an example:

```
Ac.1<-rnorm(100, 0, 1)
At.2<-rnorm(100, 0, 1)
Ae.3<-rnorm(100, 0, 1)
Ba.1<-rnorm(100, 0, 1)
Bc.2<-rnorm(100, 0, 1)
Be.3<-rnorm(100, 0, 1)
Cb.1<-rnorm(100, 0, 1)
Cy.2<-rnorm(100, 0, 1)
Cc.3<-rnorm(100, 0, 1)
```

The current data set looks like:

```
current.df<-data.frame(Ac.1,Ae.3,Ba.1,At.2,Bc.2,Cb.1,Cy.2,Be.3,Cc.3)
```

I want to create the small date frame that has the same title of "B", named`small.df`. It should look like

```
name(small.df)
[1] "Ba.1" "Bc.2" "Be.3"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform the desired process by selecting your letter.
You can use a combination of assign & regexpr to find your col and assign the final DF :

```
#Chose your Letter
 letter <- "B"

#Find columns in colnames with a regexpr
cols <- which(regexpr(paste0("^",letter),names(current.df)) != -1)

#Assign a letter variable dependant name to your new DF
assign(paste0(letter,".small.df"),current.df[,cols])
```

Hope that wil helps

Gottavianoni

Comment: It's really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to select the columns.

```
small.df <- current.df[, c("Ba.1", "Bc.2", "Be.3")]
```

Or this to select all the columns began with "B".

```
small.df <- current.df[, grepl("^B", names(current.df))]
```